# What do bums actually look like?

Tags: bums, andy-griffiths

In Andy Griffiths's series of [bum books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Griffiths#.22Bum.22_series), the central conceit is that bums (*that's "butts" to you Americans*) have minds of their own and can detach themselves from their owners' bodies at will to fly around - propelled by gas power, naturally - and wreak havoc.

What I've always wondered is: **what do the 'backs' of the bums look like when they're detached?** The bit that's visible when the bum is attached to the body presumably looks the same when it's detached, but what about the other side of the bum? Are the ends of all the veins and arteries and nerves that run between the bum and the rest of the body visible on the detached bum, or does it round out nicely with a skin covering?

---

<sub>Yes, I know it's April Fool's Day. But this *is* a serious question, which I've been meaning to ask for a long time. I even made sure to [check on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8121/31394) that the bum books are on-topic here.</sub>

Comment: .... I didn't even know this existed, and I have no words now that I know.

Comment: @amarillo No problem, [I did it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/bums/info).

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, given the visual on the video. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum I was hoping for an answer based on canon (i.e. the books) rather than the TV series, which is only very loosely linked to the books. (Btw, congrats on 200k!)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Cheers for feedback. I'll keep hunting.

Answer (score 3):

The books have now been licensed as a [cartoon property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_My_Butt_Went_Psycho!). As you can see from this trailer, the (now independent) bums simply have a smooth rear.

Comment: “Smooth as an android’s bottom, eh Data?”

Comment: @amarillo - [Not even close](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwYbEWgpRmE&feature=youtu.be&t=1m20s)